# Coyote in Gunnerkrigg Court

Tags: gunnerkrigg-court

I enjoy [Girl-Genius](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/) and saw they have a [kickstarter game](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/killer-robot-games/legendary-showdown-machines-and-magic) involving it and "Gunnerkrigg Court".  I looked online for "Gunnerkrigg Court" and then read about 1500 pages of webcomic [webcomic](http://www.gunnerkrigg.com/).

One of the most powerful characters in the story is "[Coyote](http://gunnerkrigg.wikia.com/wiki/Coyote)".  The character is loosely themed on the [Native American characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote_%28mythology%29).  While the Native American character has equals the Gunnerkrigg version does not - in the webcomic he is nearly all powerful.

All the creatures in the Gillite wood, the wild-magic opposite of the court have an honor and terror of Coyote.  Coyote is a archetypal narcissist.  The problem in the real world with narcissists is they hurt people - all other creatures are a means to an end.

Question

> What, if any, is the relationship between Coyote and the antenna that Annie's father made?

Comment: There are equals to Coyote in this world. Other gods with presumably similar power, we just don't see them much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is none.

The antenna that Annie's father made was supposed to bring his wife, Surma back from the dead. But he didn't know, that it would be done at Annie's expense.
[image]

And then we can see that Coyote REALLY cares about Annie - he got really angry when Annie's father forbid her going to the Wood. While Coyote is narcissistic trickster, he wouldn't be able to hurt Annie.

[image]

So whatever was trying to trick Antimony's father into hurting her, it wasn't Coyote.

Comment: Love transforms.  Fire-head girl loves the coyote.

Comment: It could be asserted that Coyote is trying to bring Reynardine into the wood, and knows that Reynardine loves Annie.

Comment: Coyote could easily bring Reynardine into the world. Just wake up his body.

Comment: The problem with that is that coyote wants Reynardine to be happy in the wood.  Force does not incline delight.